# select some columns form an excel sheet and insert them in an other sheet with PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel

as i said in the title i would like to select some columns from an excel sheet and insert them in an other sheet 
Here is my my code whent i test it this message would be shown

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class PHPExcel_Worksheet could not be converted to string in C:\wamp\www\zannier\index.php on line 59

the code in bold is the line 59

```
  require_once 'C:\wamp\www\zannier\Classes\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php';

    // Chargement du fichier Excel
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("zfg01_CAT.xlsx");

    /**
     * récupération de la première feuille du fichier Excel
     * @var PHPExcel_Worksheet $sheet
     */
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
    $newsheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet();


    $sheetNames = $objPHPExcel->getSheetNames();
    print_r($sheetNames);
    // On boucle sur les lignes

    foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {


        // On boucle sur les cellule de la ligne
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $cell) {

            if ($cell->getColumn() == 'G' OR $cell->getColumn() == 'H'OR $cell->getColumn() == 'I'OR $cell->getColumn() == 'L'OR $cell->getColumn() == 'P'OR $cell->getColumn() == 'X'OR $cell->getColumn() == 'AE') {


                for ($x = 'A'; $x <= 'G'; $x++) {
                    **$objPHPExcel->$newsheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($x, $cell->getRow(), $cell->getValue());**
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo '<table border="1">';
    // On boucle sur les lignes

    foreach ($newsheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {

        echo '<tr>';


        // On boucle sur les cellule de la ligne


        foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $cell) {
            echo '<td>';

            print_r($cell->getValue());

            echo '</td>';
        }
    }


    echo '<td>';
    $path = "./COLOR/" . getCell($sheet, 'G', $cell->getRow())->getValue() . ".jpg";
    ?>

    <img src= <?php echo $path ?> width="100" height="50"/>
    <?php
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    echo '</table>';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$objPHPExcel->$newsheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(....);
```

use

```
$newsheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(....)
```

You've assigned the new worksheet object to `$newsheet` so it is a worksheet `object` in its own right, not simply a property of the `$objPHPExcel` object